# Using input/output events to trigger methods in a parent component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angular

How can a child service notify a parent component of a change? I used to do this in angular 1 by $watching a variable in the child service. Unfortunately, this is no longer possible.

I tried injecting the service back into the component, but this fails, probably due to circular dependencies. Based on what I could find in current documentation, I came up with the code below:

```
AppComponent
 |
SomeComponent
 |
SomeService
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Component({
    selector: '[app-component]',
    templateUrl: 'partials/app.html',
    directives: [
        SomeComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        SomeService
    ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() { }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**SomeComponent**

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core'
import {SomeService} from '../services/some.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    templateUrl: 'partials/foo.html'
})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor() {}
    @Input set someEvent(value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

**SomeService**

```
import {EventEmitter, Output} from 'angular2/core'

export class CoreService {
    constructor() {
        this.someEvent = new EventEmitter();
    }
    @Output() someEvent: EventEmitter<any>;
    public foo() {
        this.someEvent.emit(true); // Or next(true)?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Output` must be used for components only not in services. At this level you can register on this event using the `(...)` syntax.

From the angular.io documentation (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Output-var.html):

> Declares an event-bound output property.
>
> When an output property emits an event, an event handler attached to that event the template is invoked.

For a service you need to explicitly subscribe on this event, as described below:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core'
import {SomeService} from '../services/some.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  templateUrl: 'partials/foo.html'
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(service:CoreService) {
    service.someEvent.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
}
```